# tcpprep: Command line arguments not allowed

Tags: networking, pcap, tcpreplay

I'm not sure, why executing below command on ubuntu terminal throws error. tcpprep syntax and options are mentioned as per in help doc, still throws error.

```
root@test-vm:~# /usr/bin/tcpprep --cachefile='cachefile1' —-pcap='/pcaps/http.pcap' 

tcpprep: Command line arguments not allowed
tcpprep (tcpprep) - Create a tcpreplay cache cache file from a pcap file

root@test-vm:~# /usr/bin/tcpprep -V
tcpprep version: 3.4.4 (build 2450) (debug)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your command (and it doesn't help that `tcpprep` errors are vague or wrong).

### Problem #1: Commands out of order

tcpprep requires that `-i/--pcap` come before `-o/--cachefile`. You can fix this as below, but then you get a different error:

```sh
bash$ /usr/bin/tcpprep —-pcap='/pcaps/http.pcap' --cachefile='cachefile1'

Fatal Error in tcpprep_api.c:tcpprep_post_args() line 387:
Must specify a processing mode: -a, -c, -r, -p
```

Note that the error above is not even accurate! `-e/--mac` can also be used!

### Problem #2: Processing mode must be specified

`tcpprep` is used to preprocess a capture file into client/server using a heuristic *that you provide*. Looking through the [tcpprep manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcpprep), there are 5 valid options (`-acerp`). Given this [capture file](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=14939&name=02_dcerpc_witness_changed.pcapng) as `input.pcapng` with server `192.168.122.201` and next hop mac `52:54:00:12:35:02`,

#### -a/--auto

Let tcpprep determine based on one of 5 heuristics: `bridge`, `router`, `client`, `server`, `first`. Ex:

```
tcpprep --auto=first —-pcap=input.pcapng --cachefile=input.cache
```

#### -c/--cidr

Specify server by cidr range. We see servers at 192.168.122.201, 192.168.122.202, and 192.168.3.40, so summarize with `192.168.0.0/16`:

```
tcpprep --cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --pcap=input.pcapng --cachefile=input.cache
```

#### -e/--mac

This is not as useful in this capture as ALL traffic in this capture has dest mac of next hop of `52:54:00:12:35:02`, `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` (broadcast), or `33:33:00:01:00:02` (multicast). Nonetheless, traffic from the next hop won't be client traffic, so this would look like:

```
tcpprep --mac=52:54:00:12:35:02 —-pcap=input.pcapng --cachefile=input.cache
```

#### -r/--regex

This is for IP ranges, and is an alternative to summarizing subnets with `--cidr`. This would be more useful if you have several IPs like 10.0.20.1, 10.1.20.1, 10.2.20.1, ... where summarization won't work and regex will. This is one regex we could use to summarize the servers:

```
tcpprep --regex="192\.168\.(122|3).*" —-pcap=input.pcapng --cachefile=input.cache
```

#### -p/--port

Looking at Wireshark > Statistics > Endpoints, we see ports [135,139,445,1024]/tcp, [137,138]/udp are associated with the server IPs. 1024/tcp, used with `dcerpc` is the only one that falls outside the range 0-1023, and so we'd have to manually specify it. Per [services](https://linux.die.net/man/5/services) syntax, we'd represent this as 'dcerpc    1024/tcp'. In order to specify port, we also need to specify a `--services` file. We can specify one inline as a temporary file descriptor with [process substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). Altogether,

```
tcpprep --port --services=<(echo "dcerpc    1024/tcp") --pcap=input.pcapng --cachefile=input.cache
```

### Further Reading

For more examples and information, check out [the online docs](https://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/tcpprep).